# Freezing problem of laptop

Tags: 22.04, freeze

I have originally windows 10 in my laptop (model No. HP ZBook Power 15.6 Inch G8) but I am using Ubantu 22.04 instead of it. It was working fine initially with Ubantu but now very often laptop freezes suddenly while using and I have to force shut it down. Even after restarting it again, many times it again freezes.

Comment: What is the CPU and GPU?

Comment: If the freezes happen at random moments 1st thing to do is to check the memory modules. If those show errors do replace the one with errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: I checked it is not due to memory overload.

Comment: CPU: Intel core i9-11900H 8 Core and GPU: Nvidia Quadro T1200 Graphics 4 GB DDR6

Comment: Following error is appearing on the black screen after resatrting [ 2085.931558] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from a4:9b:cd:ea:fc:4f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same problem with this laptop model.
The problem seems to be related to the dedicated NVIDIA GPU. Changing drivers did not work for me.

An acceptable solution for me was to disable the GPU completely in the BIOS (change to "UMA Graphics" in the BIOS).

I'm aware that this solution might not be acceptable for everyone if you depend on the dedicated GPU, but in my case (Software Engineer) the dedicated GPU was not really necessary and the freezes are gone completely.